# Chrome Ignoring Margin for Images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I used Firefox while working on the website.

Once completed, I opened the page in Chrome and noticed that the images are ignoring margins. Can anyone provide insight on why this is happening?

[image]

The CSS:

```
.serviceImages{
    margin-left:23%;
    max-width:212px;
    height:249px;
}
```

I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Can you paste styles you applied on parent `li` ?

Comment: Are you using any other css frameworks. If using Chrome Press F12 to open the dev console. From there you can explore the html elements and view what styles are being applied to the html elements as well as if any are overriding them. Depending upon how the element is placed in the UI can also affect this. Is it in a <div> element ? Seeing the HTML will help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I have no parent styles @enguerranws The only styles would be applied by Bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap to achieve that layout ? Some would say that's useless. Anyway, I guess it comes from the fact that `img` are inline elements. Try putting it on `display: block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @enguerranws That by itself wouldn't be the problem. In the absence of any other styles, Chrome applies the margin to imgs just as well as Firefox. ([Quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Lym0r8s8/).)So there must be something in the OP's other CSS to disrupt this.

Comment: @MrLister I also checked it in a fiddle, I think that is related to percents : http://jsfiddle.net/Lym0r8s8/2/ I was wondering : what does those 23% refers to ? 23% of what ?

Comment: @enguerranws Hey, look at that. It's supposed to be 23% of the container width. In this case, the `body`. But Chrome takes the width of the images themselves. Hm.

Comment: I simplified the fiddle, removed the bootstrap stuff, and here is the result. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Lym0r8s8/5/ Definitely a bug in Chrome. Edit: although IE behaves the same as Chrome, so it's 2 against 1. Hm.

Comment: The 23% refers to the parent which would be <div class="col-xs-12">

Comment: @MJW And Chrome thinks that the parent is the list item. Which, technically, it is.

Comment: @MJW And Chrome does as if li has no width/no content stack. If you put li some width, then the margin is applied. http://jsfiddle.net/Lym0r8s8/6/

Comment: By the way, there's no logical reason to put `margin-left` the `img` instead on its parent `li`. You are currently trying to put a margin between the list element so, put a margin on it.